# Custom module not found error on google colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run a pytorch code in google colab. The github repository is:

[GitHub - BrightXiaoHan/FaceDetector: A re-implementation of mtcnn. Joint training, tutorial and deployment together.](https://github.com/BrightXiaoHan/FaceDetector)

There is a custom module in google colab notebook. To build the module I have run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

My folder structure:

ls /content/drive/MyDrive/FaceDetector

```
doc  mtcnn  output  README.md  scripts  setup.py  tests  tutorial
```

I have also added in sys path

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/drive/MyDrive/FaceDetector')
```

So when I try to import it

```py
import mtcnn
```

I am getting an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)

[<ipython-input-61-eb80d650f81e>](https://localhost:8080/#) in <module>
----> 1 import mtcnn

---

2 frames

---

[/content/drive/MyDrive/FaceDetector/mtcnn/deploy/detect.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in <module>
      4 import time
      5 ----> 6 import mtcnn.utils.functional as func
      7       8 def _no_grad(func):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mtcnn.utils.functional'
```

Google Colab Notebook Link:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KQRF-HmZA7EU13acnwIX0dFayRMIuQ-B?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set my PYTHONPATH environment variable.

```py
!PYTHONPATH=/content/drive/My\ Drive/FaceDetector python scripts/gen_pnet_train.py
```